# Changing length of the edges in Networkx lib

Tags: python, plot, networkx

I have started working with networkx lib a few days ago. I'm wondering if its possible to change length of the edges on the graph?
I have plotted a graph but nodes are very close one to another, so node names are overlapping (check the image below).
This is my code:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Defining graph .Graph() and .DiGraph()
analysis_graph = nx.DiGraph()


# Adding relations to the graph
analysis_graph.add_edges_from(relation_list)


# extracting nodes from relations - Unique node entities
node_list = list(nx.nodes(analysis_graph))
print(type(node_list))


# Creating sizes for each node (degree - number of relations from each node)
dict_of_node_sizes = dict(analysis_graph.degree) # for getting node sizes
print(dict_of_node_sizes)


# Same graph each time
my_pos = nx.spring_layout(analysis_graph.to_undirected(), seed = 0)
#.to_undirected() -> Making shape of directed graph like undirected graph


# Printing graph info
print(nx.info(analysis_graph))


# Printing graph
plt.figure(figsize=(25,17))
nx.draw(analysis_graph, 
        pos = my_pos, 
        with_labels = True, 
        arrowsize=10, 
        font_size=10, 
        node_size=[(v+1) * 120 for v in dict_of_node_sizes.values()])
```

This is my graph:

[image]

Do you know how I can fix the look of the graph so that nods are clearly visible?
Should I make longer edges (how) or should I change the fonts, or something else?

Comment: analysis_graph.add_edge('A', 'B', length = 1)

Comment: analysis_graph.add_edges_from([(1, 2), (2, 3)], weight=3)

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18199794/add-edges-from-three-tuples-networkx

Comment: It does not work, It doesn't change

Comment: Im passing list to the 'analysis_graph.add_edges_from(relation_list)', I have tried to add length = 1, and length = 10, but the result is the same

Comment: Increase the figure size and then plot with a vectorized format like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68762464/how-to-develop-a-vectorized-navigable-graph-using-matplotlib-and-networkx/68853061#68853061).  For example, use `fig = plt.figure(figsize=(50,34))` and then save the output with `fig.savefig('filename.eps', format='eps')`.  I would also consider changing the `node_color` and `edge_color` params of `nx.draw()` for better contrast with black text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main problem is that nodes and labels overlap. As both are in a dark color, neither is clearly visible. However, the node layout actually seems to be pretty good, as it accentuates the hub-structure of the graph. So I would not change the edge length to space the nodes further apart.

In my opinion, your first option is to de-emphasize the nodes and edges, such that the labels become easier to read. This can be achieved by making the nodes and edges a lighter color.

Your second option is to offset the node labels from the nodes. However, this is non-trivial as you will want to prevent node label overlaps with other labels, other nodes, and the edges of the graph. Unfortunately, [there isn't any functionality within networkx that reduces node label overlaps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11946005/2912349). However, to deal with this and other issues, I wrote [netgraph](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph), which is a network visualisation library and compatible with networkx graphs.
My approach to avoiding node label overlaps is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67821673/2912349). However, if you tell netgraph to draw labels at a scalar offset, it will do just that, so there isn't anything special for you to do.

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import random
import string
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

from netgraph import Graph # pip install netgraph

# create random graph with hubs and leafs
hubs = np.random.randint(5, 15, size=10)
leafs = np.ones((np.sum(hubs)), dtype=int)
degrees = np.concatenate([hubs, leafs])
g = nx.configuration_model(degrees, create_using=nx.Graph)
giant_component = next(nx.connected_components(g))
h = g.subgraph(giant_component)

# generate random labels
def random_string(length):
    # https://stackoverflow.com/a/2030081/2912349
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for ii in range(length))

labels = {node : random_string(5) for node in h}

# generate node sizes
node_size = dict(g.degree)
nx_node_size = np.array([100*node_size[node] for node in h])
ng_node_size = {node : np.sqrt(size) for node, size in node_size.items()}

# same positions for comparability
node_layout = nx.spring_layout(h)

# plot
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(20, 12))
nx.draw(h, pos=node_layout, labels=labels, node_size=nx_node_size, node_color='lightgray', edge_color='darkgray', ax=ax1)
Graph(h, node_layout=node_layout, node_labels=labels, node_label_offset=0.1, node_size=ng_node_size, ax=ax2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Can you just explain me line by line what you did?
The answer is amazing!

Comment: Which part do you not understand?